# Solidworks dwg with bendlines, how do i merge these two codes?

Tags: vba, solidworks, dxf, dwg

I have these two codes (harvested on internet) that separately are doing great. But i need them to be one.
My main objective is to generate only one file, and not two, as this code is retrieving; and with the same as my part.

This one is working great, both is actualy, but this is creating two dxf files and I only need one of them. Beside, it create using the "view name" i rather it to be the file name.

https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/document/drawing/export-sheet-metal-views/

The next one doesnt works properly but it uses the file name, to name the new file.
[Macro to export Solidworks Part to dxf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75185165/macro-to-export-solidworks-part-to-dxf)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on this code:

https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/document/drawing/export-sheet-metal-views/

Tested with one drawing that has already been saved and with only one view that is a flat-pattern view.

To solve the question of having two files being saved replace this code:

```
Sub ExportFlatPatternViews(draw As SldWorks.DrawingDoc, sheet As SldWorks.sheet)
    
    Dim vViews As Variant
    
    vViews = sheet.GetViews()
    
    If Not IsEmpty(vViews) Then
        
        Dim i As Integer
        
        For i = 0 To UBound(vViews)
            Dim swView As SldWorks.view
            Set swView = vViews(i)
            
            If swView.IsFlatPatternView() Then
                ExportFlatPatternView draw, swView
            End If
        Next
        
    End If    
End Sub
```

With this one:

```
    Sub ExportFlatPatternViews(draw As SldWorks.DrawingDoc, sheet As SldWorks.sheet)
    
    Dim swView As SldWorks.view
    
    Set swView = draw.GetFirstView
    
    Set swView = swView.GetNextView
    
    While Not swView Is Nothing
    
        If swView.IsFlatPatternView Then
        
            ExportFlatPatternView draw, swView
            
         End If
         
         Set swView = swView.GetNextView
         
     Wend
     
End Sub
```

For some reason the original code is getting the same view twice, but with different names. Would need some more time to check why.

To save with filename change the code where `filename` is being assigned.

```
'fileName = view.Name & OUT_EXT

Dim saveDir As String
saveDir = model.GetPathName()

If saveDir = "" Then
    Err.Raise vbError, "", "Only saved drawings are supported"
End If

fileName = model.GetTitle & OUT_EXT
```

Since the `ModelDoc2` is as drawing file the `ModelDoc2.GetTitle` will return the file name and the sheet name.